# Proper tutorial on setting up iis7 with an asp.net mvc4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, webdeploy

My work has some dedicated web servers (Server 2008R2, IIS7). Currently everything done here before has just been asp.net webforms. For a new project I want to finally introduce them to MVC. I have a vanilla MVC application created in VS2013. I walked through some different sites and got it set up on my local IIS (full, not express) just fine. I can hit 'localhost' and see the site I created. I am using web deploy, and it worked very well.

After that I moved on to our development server. I set it all up the same (i.e new website in iis, web deploy set up with proper credentials, etc). Publishing from VS works. On the development server I see all the files there, but in IIS on the server (via RDP session) I cannot browse to it. It does **not** give me a 404 or 503 error, internet explorer just tells me that it can't find the address.

Based off the many, many articles I went through I did the following:

1. aspnet_regiis.exe -i (32 and 64 bit)
2. Made sure the server has Web Deploy 3.5 and Web Deploy tools 2.1 installed.
3. Added some lines to my web.config (see below)****.
4. made sure the server had .net 4.5 and mvc installed.

After all that it still will not show me the site. Anything I am missing? I would love to find a tutorial to walk me through baby-step by baby-step, but all I see out there assumes that you already have x and y set up, or you already know IIS like the back of your hand.

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
  <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
</modules>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**To deploy MVC4 Application onto IIS 7.5**

1. Make sure that you installed the latest framework.
2. Go to `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe –ir` for 32 bit or
   `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe –ir` for 64 to register asp.net
3. To be able to work with sites in MVC for IIS7 ir IIS7.5 please update it (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368).(Good)
4. Make sure that there is:

   ```
   <modules>
     <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
     <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" 
          preCondition="" />
     <!-- any other modules you want to run in MVC 
          e.g. FormsAuthentication, Roles etc. -->
   </modules>
   ```

in web.config. (Good)

5. Make sure that there is

   ```
   <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   </system.webServer>
   ```

   in web.config.(Bad)

from own experience... use "Good"

Comment: thanks @anton.  I'm  heading  into  work  now,  I'll  double check  these  steps  when I  arrive.

Comment: Alright, I believe this worked. I did however still run into the same issue, but after talking to my network guy he let me know my issue was DNS related. the site itself was set up fine. Like I said, serverIlliterate == me.